# Inspecting OutputCache and HttpRuntime.Cache in production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

Is there a tool or nuget package that facilitate OutputCache and HttpRuntime.Cache inspection in production environment?

In development environment I can just set a breakpoint and inspect the cache from the immediate window.

I can always roll my own cache inspection controller but if there is a tool already built for that, I'd rather not waste effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Glimpse`](http://getglimpse.com/). It allows you to inspect the values of vital server side variables. AFAIK it doesn't support Cache but it is trivially easy to write a [custom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997580/29407) and enable support.